# ASP.NET MVC open a Excel file on click of button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I display a table with data on the page and then when user clicks Export I put the data in the excel file. Now I want to open this file so that user can save it or just view it. This is the code I have. It prompts the user to save a file but that file is the whole page!! WHat is wrong here?

```
   string filename = filePath.Substring(12);
                        System.IO.File.Copy(filePath, "C:/Work/MCTestSuiteCertificate/TS.ToDoViewer/Content/" + filename, true);
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.ContentType = @"application\xls";
                       // FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + filename));
                        Response.AddHeader("Filename", filename);
                        Response.ContentType = "application/xls";
                        Response.TransmitFile("C:/Work/MCTestSuiteCertificate/TS.ToDoViewer/Content/" + filename);
                        //Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                        Response.Flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `File` method (which returns `FileResult`). You should not work directly with `Response` in MVC application.

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    ...
    string filename = filePath.Substring(12);
    return File(Path.Combine(@"C:\Work\MCTestSuiteCertificate\TS.ToDoViewer\Content", filename), "application/xls");
}
```

PS Also please note use of `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation.

Comment: @Serg When I do this I get no error - BUT excel is not opened either. I call it with:
**
<input type="submit" value="Report" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("YourAction", "Employee" )'" />**

Comment: Check the HTTP calls between client and server to find out where the issue lies.